# Is it possible to get a UK visitor visa after 2 years?

Tags: uk

It may seem weird but I need your opinion based on your travel experience. My friend was a student in the UK and had been working illegally there and immigration officers caught him. He told them to leave voluntarily and he had left the UK 2 years ago.

Is it possible to get a visitor visa after 2 years? He was informed by the officer that he could come to the UK 1 year after the ban.

Comment: If they said the ban was only 1 year long then your friend can certainly apply now, it will be difficult to get a visa after that but it certainly is not impossible since the ban is over.

Comment: Does he still have any letter they gave him, or any stamp in his passport to confirm the ban was exactly one year? The letter might give more detailed information about his options.

Comment: The only way to find out is to apply. Your friend will need to demonstrate a good reason for wanting to return, very strong ties to his home country and robust financials to stand any chance of convincing UK Immigration that he won’t breach visa rules again.

Comment: Please write answers as answers, not as comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend breached the conditions of his visa and departed voluntarily after the initiation of removal. The documentation he received would have indicated the applicable re-entry ban, e.g., 12 months if the individual leaves the UK voluntarily and at their own expense.

He certainly can apply for leave to enter the UK, and must if he is a visa national, should if he is a non-visa national. While a non-visa national does not normally need advance permission to enter the United Kingdom, it would be advisable to do so with such an immigration history.

Understand that his breach and removal are part of his record, permanently, and will be considered when he asks to be allowed to return to the UK.